# Create matrix (2d-array) of size specified by parameter input in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, function, matrix, arguments

I am learning C++ with experiencein mostly Python, R and SQL.

The way arrays (and vectors which differes somehow from 1d-arrays? and matrices which are 2d-arrays?) work in C++ seems quite different as I cannot specify the size of dimension of the array with an argument from the function.

A toy-example of my goal is some thing like this:

1. Have a function **my_2d_array** which takes two arguments *M* and *N* and returns a matrix or 2d-array of dimension *(MxN)* with  elements indicating the position of that element. E.g. calling *my_2d_array(4,3)* would return:

   [[00, 01, 02],
   [10, 11, 12],
   [20, 21, 22],
   [30, 31, 32]]
2. The **main** function should execute **my_2d_array** and be able to potentially perform calculations with the result or modify it.

This is my attempt (with errors):

```
int my_2d_array(int N, int M) {
    int A[N][M];
    
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < M; j++) {
            std::string element = std::to_string(i) + std::to_string(j);
            A[i][j] = element;
        }
    }
    return A;
}


void main() {
    int N, M;
    N = 4;
    M = 3;

    int A[N][M] = my_2d_array(N, M);

    // Print the array A
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < M; j++) {
            std::cout << A[i][j] << " ";
        }
        std::cout << "\n";
    }

}
```

One (1) dimensional attempt of @JustLearning's suggestion:

```
int my_array(int N) {
    std::array<int, N> A;

    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        A[i] = i;
    }
    return A;
}


int main() {
    int N = 4;

    int A[N] = my_array(N);

    // Print the array A
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        std::cout << A[i] << " ";
    }

}
```

Comment: Just use a `std::vector`.

Comment: Okay, I am not entirely sure how to do this. I think of a vector being 1 dimensional. But I guess you are suggestion to change my line *int A[N][M]* in **my_2d_array** somehow?

Comment: @Landscape Arrays and vectors are containers. Don't think of them as being n-dimensional. If you want a matrix, you need to *use* a container like a matrix. For example, you can have a vector `v` of size `N*M` from which you access an element `(i, j)` by doing `v[i*M+j]`. Whether you need a plain array, a `std::array`, or a `std::vector`, or even some other container type, depends on considerations other than multidimentionality. For example, runtime or compile-time size.

Comment: @Nelfeal this is somewhat confusing to me (perhaps because I studie quite formal math).  I am not familiar with *containers* (I will Google it now) but if I understand you correct then vectors and arrays are different types of *objects* and *containers*. That is they have different properties? And vectors are not necessarily limited to be 1 dimensional? Hence a matrix (from math) can be implemented as either a 2d array or a 2d vector depending on the usecase?

Comment: A `std::vector` of size `M` * `N` will do fine to hold both dimensions, but if it makes things easier for your to think about you can also often use `std::vector<std::vector<>>` - a vector of vectors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following your comment, I can see why you are confused in your attempts to use a matrix in code.

There are many types of containers in C++. Many of them you can find in the standard library (`std::vector`, `std::list`, `std::set`, ...), others you can create yourself or use other libraries. Plain arrays (like `int a[5]`) are a somewhat unique case because they come from C and are part of the language itself.

A plain array lives on the stack (not very important but you might want to read up on stack vs heap allocations), and refers to a contiguous region of memory.

If you declare some array `a` like `int a[5]`, you get a region of 5 integers one after the other, and you can point to the first one by just writing `a`. You can access each of them using `a[i]` or, equivalently, `*(a+i)`.

If you declare `a` like `int a[5][3]`, you now get a region of 15 integers, but you can access them slightly differently, like `a[i][j]`, which is equivalent to `*(a+i*3+j)`.

The important thing to you here is that the sizes (5 and 3) must be compile-time constants, and you cannot change them at runtime.

The same is true for `std::array`: you could declare `a` like `std::array<std::array<int, 3, 5> a` and get a similar region of 15 integers, that you can access the same way, but with some convenience (for example you can return that type, whereas you cannot return a plain array type, only a pointer, losing the size information in the process).

My advice is not to think of these arrays as having dimensionality, but as simple containers that give you some memory to work with however you choose. You can very well declare `a` like `std::array<int, 15> a` and access elements in a 2D way by indexing like this: `a[i*3+j]`. Memory-wise, it's the same.

Now, if you want the ability to set the sizes at runtime, you can use `std::vector` in a similar way. Either you declare `a` like `std::vector<std::vector<int>> a(5, std::vector<int>(3))` and deal with the nested vectors (that initialization creates 5 `std::vector<int>` of size 3 each), or you declare `a` as a single vector like `std::vector<int> a(15)` and index it like `a[i*3+j]`. You can even make your own class that wraps a vector and helps with the indexing.

Either way, it's rare in C++ to need a plain array, and you should generally use some kind of container, with `std::vector` being a good choice for a lot of things.

Here is an example of how your code would look like using vectors:

```
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

std::vector<std::string> my_2d_array(int N, int M) {
    std::vector<std::string> A(N*M);
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < M; j++) {
            std::string element = std::to_string(i) + std::to_string(j);
            A[i*M+j] = element;
        }
    }
    return A;
}

int main() {
    int N, M;
    N = 4;
    M = 3;
    std::vector<std::string> A = my_2d_array(N, M);

    // Print the array A
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < M; j++) {
            std::cout << A[i*M+j] << " ";
        }
        std::cout << "\n";
    }
}
```

And here is a *very* crude example of a Matrix class used to wrap the vectors:

```
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

template<typename T>
class Matrix {
public:
    Matrix(int rowCount, int columnCount) : v(rowCount*columnCount), columnCount(columnCount) {}
    T& operator()(int row, int column) {
        return v[row*columnCount + column];
    }

private:
    std::vector<T> v;
    int columnCount;
};

Matrix<std::string> my_2d_array(int N, int M) {
    Matrix<std::string> A(N, M);
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < M; j++) {
            std::string element = std::to_string(i) + std::to_string(j);
            A(i, j) = element;
        }
    }
    return A;
}

int main() {
    int N, M;
    N = 4;
    M = 3;
    Matrix<std::string> A = my_2d_array(N, M);

    // Print the array A
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < M; j++) {
            std::cout << A(i, j) << " ";
        }
        std::cout << "\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Your answer contains lots of information explained in a clear manner!

Answer (score 2):

Welcome to C++! Your function `my_2d_array` has a couple of issues:

- the return type is `int`, however you are attempting to return an array of `int`s.
- the identifier of an array in C++ is actually a pointer to the first element of that array. Therefore, when you return `A`, you must be aware of how it should be passed to a new variable in the `main` part of the code. In particular, your code is passing a reference to a *temporary* variable `A`, which is not permitted or safe.

In addition, in C++, unless you know what you're doing, `main` should always return an `int`:

```
int main() { ... }
```

What is not clear from your question is whether you are attempting to implement your own "array" class, or simply want to use arrays already established in the standard. For the latter, [std::array](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array) is a good place to start. The advantage is that you can return `std::array`s from functions like you return `int`s or `double`s.

`std::array`s are good if you plan to work with arrays of *fixed* size, as the size becomes part of the type: `std::array<int, 3> my_array;`. Then you can fill it in manually or with member functions of the class (see dox linked above).

If for some reason you prefer to work with arrays of dynamical size (sizes that will change during running your program), `std::vector` is the way to go.

Finally, if you are actually learning C++ by attempting to implement a container `MyArray`, you should specify that in your question and be a bit more specific in what help you need.

Here's a working example in 1d:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <array>

template <int N>
std::array<int, N> my_array() {
    std::array<int, N> A;                                                                                                                                                                    
                                                                                                                                                                                             
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {                                                                                                                                                            
        A[i] = i;                                                                                                                                                                            
    }                                                                                                                                                                                        
    return A;                                                                                                                                                                                
}                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
                                                                                                                                                                                             
int main() {                                                                                                                                                                                 
    const int N = 4;                                                                                                                                                                         
                                                                                                                                                                                             
    std::array<int, N> arr = my_array<N>();                                                                                                                                                  
                                                                                                                                                                                             
    // Print the array A                                                                                                                                                                     
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {                                                                                                                                                            
        std::cout << arr[i] << " ";                                                                                                                                                          
    }                                                                                                                                                                                        
}
```

Since the size of a `std::array` is included it its *type*, you need to create a function *template*, which is basically a function that works for different types. (In C++, `std::array<int, 3>` and `std::array<int, 4>` are considered *different* types.)

In order to use this in `main`, the index is promoted to a `const int`, as plain `int`s can vary during run time, and therefore are not suitable for defining types. (In C++ jargon, look up *constant expressions*).

Finally, note that both the return type and the type of the variable that receives the value returned by the function must be `std::array`, not `int` as you tried in your 1d code.

Comment: By the way, if you decide to go with containers decided in the standard, multiple-dimensional arrays are constructed by nesting its type in the template parameter: `std::array<<std::array, M>, N>`. This  is OK while you learn, but it may not be super efficient for large matrices in real life. In such cases you should look up advanced linear algebra libraries.

Comment: Thank you, lots of information in your answer - I will surely have to Google a lot of the topics your are mentioning. 

I've tried to simplify my problem to a 1-dimensional case following your answer. It is still not working (likely from N being an argument). If possible, can you then show me how your solution is implemented in the 1d case?

Comment: I edited my answer to include an example.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a 2d vector like this

```
vector<vector int> A;
```

It works the same way as a 2d array

Comment: It does *not* work the same way a 2D array does. Among other things, the allocated memory won't be contiguous.